# Must XML end tag names match XML end tag names exactly?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, .net-4.0

I have the following XML (test example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" >
<Styles>
<Style ss:ID="s21"><NumberFormat ss:Format="@"/></Style>
</Styles>
<Worksheet ss:Name="--">
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="1" ss:ExpandedRowCount="1" x:FullColumns="1" x:FullRows="1" ss:StyleID="s21">
    <Column ss:StyleID="s21" ss:Width="184"/>
    <Row>   
        <Cell><ss:Data ss:Type="String">42</Data></Cell>
</Row></Table></Worksheet></Workbook>
```

When trying to read the file using [DataSet.ReadXml()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/360dye2a(v=vs.110).aspx), the following exception is generated: `The 'ss:Data' start tag on line 12 position 14 does not match the end tag of 'Data'. Line 12, position 43.`
While all examples in W3C documentation show namespace-qualified end tags, MS Excel opens such file without any warnings.

Setting `DataSet.Namespace = "ss";` doesn't change anything.

What can be done to read such file, preferably without adding extra libraries?

Comment: Should be : </ss:Data>

Comment: @jdweng Yes, it seems that perfect XML shouldn't be like this. My question is: given this XML, without any freedom to change it, how should I parse it? Replacing all instances of "</Data>" with "</ss:Data>" and all instances of "<Data>" with "<ss:Data>" will probably work, but I wonder if there is an "easier" way.

Comment: @Abstraction: It's not just "perfect" XML that shouldn't be like this.  *Any* XML *cannot* be like this, else it's not XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, XML end tags must match XML start tags exactly, including any namespace prefixes.**

From your question:

> What can be done to read such file, preferably without adding extra
>   libraries?

The XML must be repaired to be well-formed if it's to be parsed successfully using compliant XML tools.  In particular, you must change the the end-tag as [@jdweng suggests in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573535/tag-mismatch-in-system-data-dataset-readxml-ssdata-data/45573936#comment78106915_45573535): `</ss:Data>`

Per the [W3C XML Recommendation, section 3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags):

> [Definition: The end of every element that begins with a start-tag
>   must be marked by an **end-tag** containing a name that echoes the
>   element's type as given in the start-tag:]

From your question:

> While all examples in W3C documentation show namespace-qualified end
>   tags, MS Excel opens such file without any warnings.

Then MS Excel isn't processing the XML in a compliant manner and may well be missing other issues.

See also [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765194/how-to-parse-invalid-bad-not-well-formed-xml)

Comment: Thank you. Mainly I was afraid that I was missing something like `XmlReadMode` value while the file was actually a well-formed XML. Now I evidently have to use option 3. of your answer to the linked question. Is there a direct quote that start and end tags must be either both prefixed or both unprefixed? W3C page - https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml-names/ - gives the impression that one can expand `STag ETag` into `'<' QName (S Attribute)* S? '>' '</' QName S? '>'` and then into `'<' PrefixedName '></' UnprefixedName '>'`.

Comment: Answer updated to show where in the XML Recommendation it says that end tag names must match start tag names.