# How can I validate my 3,000,000 line long XML file?

Tags: xml, validation, xml-parsing, notepad++, large-data

I have an XML file. It is nearly correct, but it is not.

```
Error on line 302211.
Extra Content at the end of the document.
```

I've spent literally two days trying to debug this, but the file is so big it's nearly impossible. Is there anything I can do ?

Here are the relevant lines also (I include 2 lines before the error code, the error begins on the `<seg>` tag).

```
 <tu>
   <tuv xml:lang="en"> 
    <prop type="feed"></prop>
    <seg>
        <bpt i="1" x="1" type="feed">
            test
        </bpt>
        To switch on computer:
        <ept i="1">
            &gt;
        </ept>
        Press device 
        <ph x="2" type="feed">
            &lt;schar _TR=&quot;123&quot; y.io.name
        </ph> or 
        <ph x="3" type="feed">
            &lt;schar _TR=&quot;274&quot; y.io.name=&quot;
        </ph> (Spain) twice. 
    </seg>
 </tuv>
</tu>
```

Can anyone give me some pointers on finding the issue here? I am using the Notepad++ XML plugin.

Comment: @B001 Sorry I didnt include the opening <tu>, it's added now. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Try running your file through `xmllint` from [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/).

Comment: THe XML you posted looks valid, where's the error?

Comment: @WilliamWalseth I wish I knew!! XMLLint and Notepad++ are giving me the same error as above :)

Comment: misleading question... it is about wellformedness not validity

Answer (score 3):

### Background notes

- The XML fragment you've posted stands on its own as a well-formed XML
  document – the problem must be somewhere else in your XML.
- Your particular XML problem is [***well-formedness*, not
  validity**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

### Tips for finding XML well-formedness problems

1. Use an XML parser with better diagnostic messages.  Xerces-based
   tools have very good messages (albeit with a [*few exceptions*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19889132/290085)).
2. Know the common problems that cause an XML document not to be
   well-formed:

   - [Missing or mismatched element closing tag.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45573535/290085)
   - [Missing or mismatched attribute quote delimiter.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47534409/290085)
   - [`<` or `&` in content rather than `&lt` or `&amp;`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085)
   - [Multiple root elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44592719/290085)
   - [Incomplete markup after the root element.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46355454/290085)
   - [Multiple XML declarations, or an XML declaration appears other than at the top of the document.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19898942/290085)
3. Divide and conquer.  Consider this sketch of a huge XML document:

   ```
   <root>
      <First>
          <FirstChild>
             <!-- Tons of descendent markup -->
          </FirstChild>
          <SecondChild>
             <!-- Tons of descendent markup -->
          </SecondChild>
      </First>
      <Second>
          <!-- Tons of descendent markup -->
      </Second>
   </root>
   ```

   **Process of elimination:**

   1. Delete the `First` element.
   2. Revalidate.
   3. If error goes away, restore `First` element and remove `Second` element.
   4. Else, remove `FirstChild` element.
   5. Repeat until error can be more easily spotted in the reduced XML document.

### See also

- **[How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)**

Comment: Many thanks for this. Can you recommend a Xerces based parser for me on Windows please? :)

Comment: I've long ago stopped tracking implementation technologies of XML tools, but if you're not up for using [**Xerces**](http://xerces.apache.org/) directly, try [**Oxygen XML Editor**](https://www.oxygenxml.com/) for a full editor or [**Saxon .NET**](https://www.saxonica.com/download/dotnet.xml) for command line work.