# Google Earth KML Parse Error

Tags: xml, error-handling, kml, google-earth, parse-error

I'm getting the following parse error when trying to upload and kml to google earth:
Parse error at line 1, column 1: unclosed token

The start of the code looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.0">
       <Document>
           <name>BLAST EXCLUSION</name>
```

Could anyone suggest what the issue is?

Thanks

Comment: I have now got this code to work in Google Earth Pro. Previously I was using the web version. Is the web version just shit or do you need to make some code changes?

Comment: The error exists further down in your XML.  Make sure that the end tag, `</kml>`, exists, is in lowercase, is spelled corrected, etc.  If that doesn't help, try the [**Divide and conquer technique** listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47533201/290085).

Answer (score 0):

Simpler is better. Leave off the opening decorations and just use the most basic KML practical. GE will insert defaults for you. I'm not sure how useful the doc/folder/lookat/etc. is in the web version.

```
    <Placemark>
        <name>Untitled Placemark</name>
        <Point><coordinates>-120.3763091739549,35.34618575907946,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
```

In the desktop version you can just paste the above KML into the temp folder and it will display. You can also copy any object and it will place the KML on the clipboard. For web version place the KML into a file and import.