# System FormatException + PrintTicket

Tags: c#, xml, printing, formatexception

I have a problem that I dont understand how to fix it. Specially I work at project (C#,VB 2015) with orders, receipts etc and when I run at debug mode everything works great. But when I made a setup of my project and run my application this error appeared:

```
System.FormatException: PrintTicket XML is not well-formed. Root element is missing. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
   at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(Stream inStream)
   at MS.Internal.Printing.Configuration.InternalPrintTicket..ctor(Stream xmlStream)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MS.Internal.Printing.Configuration.InternalPrintTicket..ctor(Stream xmlStream)
   at System.Printing.PrintTicket..ctor(Stream xmlStream)
   at System.Printing.Interop.PrintTicketConverter.InternalConvertDevModeToPrintTicket(PTProviderBase provider, Byte[] devMode, PrintTicketScope scope)
   at System.Printing.PrintTicketManager.ConvertDevModeToPrintTicket(Byte[] devMode)
   at System.Printing.PrintQueue.get_UserPrintTicket()
   at Simple.Printing.PrintService.PrintOrder(IEnumerable`1 templates, Order order, Shift shift, IList`1 printingPosts, SimpleConfiguration configuration, Boolean showPrices, Invoice invoice, Boolean skipPosts, Int32 postPosition)
   at Simple.Domain.Services.OrderService.<>c__DisplayClass3c.<PrintOrder>b__39()
```

and I cant print my order. The code where my program is crushed is that :

```
var printer = dialog.PrintQueue;
var ticket = printer.UserPrintTicket ?? printer.DefaultPrintTicket;
var capabilities = printer.GetPrintCapabilities(ticket);
ticket.CopyCount = post.Copies > 0 ? post.Copies : ticket.CopyCount;
```

Comment: I need to see sample of xml file.  This looks similar to previous posting where I responded with a good solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46220779/c-sharp-read-xml-file-not-correctly-formatted/46221333#comment79463888_46221333

Comment: i dont use any of xml file.i just create a printticket and then print a xml class like this:
 OrderKitchen2 receipt = new OrderKitchen2(model);
 Visual visual = (UIElement)receipt.FindName("visual");
 var stackpanel = (StackPanel)visual;
 stackpanel.Measure  ...
 stackpanel.Arrange  ..
 var paginator = new VisualPaginator(visual as FrameworkElement);
 paginator.PageSize = ...
 paginator.PrinterMargins = ...
dialog.PrintDocument(paginator);

Comment: Not true.  The code is either parsing an xml string or reading an xml file.  I need to see the xml to seolve issue.  I think the GetPrintCapabilities() is returning an xml string, or ticket is not valid.

Comment: Same problem here. The XML Exception happens inside the .NET Framework and not inside my code.

Comment: @GiannisTsilafakis: Did you have this error only on one specific printer? For us it only seems to happen on one specific POS Thermal Printer