# how to ignore attribute without quotes in xml

Tags: html, xml, bash, xmlstarlet

i want to count how many times tag1 occurs
givin this 123.xml file ( streaming from the internet)

```
<startend>

 <tag1 name=myname>
<date>10-10-10</date>
</tag1 >

 <tag1 name=yourname>
   <date>11-10-10</date>
  </tag1 >

 </startend>
```

using : **xmlstarlet sel -t -v  "count(//tag1)" 123.xml**

output :

AttValue: " or ' expected
attributes construct error

**how to ignore that the attribute has no " "  ?**

Comment: What you have is not XML. It's a bunch of text with a few angle brackets here and there. There is no way you can feed that to xmlstarlet. There are two options. 1) Fix the producer of this mess, if you can. 2) If you can't, use html tidy in XML mode to repair the input before you give it to xmlstarlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You input XML/HTML structure has invalid tags/attributes and should be recovered beforehand:

**`xmlstarlet`** solution:

```
xmlstarlet fo -o -R -H -D 123.xml 2>/dev/null | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "count(//tag1)" -n
```

The output:

```
2
```

---

Details:

- `fo (or format)` - Format XML document(s)
- `-o or --omit-decl` - omit xml declaration
- `-R or --recover` - try to recover what is parsable
- `-D or --dropdtd` - remove the DOCTYPE of the input docs
- `-H or --html` - input is HTML
- `2>/dev/null` - suppress errors/warnings

Comment: The first invocation of **xmlstarlet** is an *excellent* solution to repairing XML problems -- added to my canonical [**How to parse bad XML answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765546/290085) with citation.  Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

XML always requires quotes around attribute values. If you want to keep using XML, you first must produce valid XML from your input. You could use an SGML processor such as OpenSP (in particular, the `osx` program) to format your input into wellformed XML. It's as simple as invoking `osx <your Input file>` on it.

If you're on Ubuntu/Debian Linux, you can install `osx` by invoking `sudo apt-get install opensp` on the command line (and similarly on other Unix systems).