# Invalid characters in XML values

Tags: c#, xml, sanitize

I'm trying to load a XML file coming from a web request. 
The response is encoded in Base64String so I have to decode it first.

```
    XmlDocument ResultXML = new XmlDocument();
    ....
    // encPayload is the string returning from web request
    byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(encPayload);
    string decodedString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
    ResultXML.LoadXml(decodedString);
```

The decoded string contains the XML that I want to load, but some values contains illegal characters (i.e '<', '>'), so I have to remove them before I can call XmlDocument LoadXml function. 
The decoded string can reach about 60/80 MB, so if I try to use Replace method I have OutOfMemoryException.
How can I fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: Is it feasible to change the source to simply give you valid XML to start with? In general, I don't trust "replacements" to sanitize XML - if they're producing invalid XML in one way today, they could be producing invalid XML in a different way tomorrow.

Comment: No, I can't change the source because it is a remote server response.

Comment: Your root problem how to parse bad "XML".  Even if your decoded data were small enough to do lexical search-and-replace, you still wouldn't know how to differentiate between a `<` in text and a `<` that starts markup without parsing.  Therefore, I'm closing this as a duplicate of [**How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)

Comment: My point is that you should get in touch with whatever organization is producing the server response, and let them know that it's invalid, assuming it's meant to be correct XML.