# Elements Inside Opening Tag

Tags: python, html, css, xpath, scrapy

I am writing a spider to download all images on the front page of a subreddit using scrapy. To do so, I have to find the image links to download the images from and use a CSS or XPath selector.

Upon inspection, the links are provided but the HTML looks like this for all of them:

```
<div class="expando expando-uninitialized" style="display: none" data-cachedhtml=" <div class="media-preview" id="media-preview-7lp06p" style="max-width: 861px"> <div class="media-preview-content"> <a href="https://i.redd.it/29moua43so501.jpg" class="may-blank"> <img class="preview" src="https://i.redditmedia.com/Q-LKAeFelFa9wAdrnvuwCMyXLrs0ULUKMsJTXSf3y34.jpg?w=861&amp;s=69085fb507bed30f1e4228e83e24b6b2" width="861" height="638"> </a> </div> </div> " data-pin-condition="function() {return this.style.display != 'none';}"><span class="error">loading...</span></div>
```

From what I can tell, it looks like all of the new elements are being initialized inside the opening tag of the `<div>` element. Could you explain what exactly is going on here, and how one would go about extracting image information from this?

*Sorry, I'm not quite sure how to properly format the html code, but there really isn't all too much to format, as it is all one big tag anyway.

Comment: Well, the HTML is faulty, that's for sure. But I'm not sure if everything following `data-cachedhtml` is supposed to be the value of this attribute (in which case, the `"` quotes inside should be escaped, up until the `<div> </div>`) or if there's a something missing like `">` right before the `<div class="media-preview"`.

Answer (score 1):

### How to read the mangled attribute, `data-cachedhtml`

The HTML is a mess.  Try the techniques listed in ***[How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)*** to get viable markup before using XPath.  It may take three passes:

1. Cleanup the markup mess.
2. Get the attribute value of `data-cachedhtml`.
3. Use XPath to extract the image links.

### XPath part

For the de-mangled `data-chachedhtml` in this form:

```
<div class="media-preview" id="media-preview-7lp06p" style="max-width: 861px">
  <div class="media-preview-content">
    <a href="https://i.redd.it/29moua43so501.jpg" class="may-blank">
      <img class="preview" src="https://i.redditmedia.com/elided"
           width="861" height="638"/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <span class="error">loading...</span>
</div>
```

1. This XPath will retrieve the preview image links:

   ```
   //a/img/@src
   ```

   (That is, all `src` attributes of `img` element children of `a` elements.)

or

2. This XPath will retrieve the click-through image links:

   ```
   //a[img]/@href
   ```

   (That is, all `href` attributes of the `a` elements that have a `img` child.)

---