# Copy HTML tag <meta> with XSLT doesn't work

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have an XML that contains an HTML file. I am trying to extract just the html file from the xml but I got an error related to the  tag:

> Error on line 41 column 3
>     SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: The element type "META" must be terminated by the
>     matching end-tag "".

How can I extract the HTML file?
This is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="SyncSAP_JMS">     <!-- source bod name -->
    <SyncReckitt>                     <!-- target bod name -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ApplicationArea"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="DataArea"/>
    </SyncReckitt>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ApplicationArea">
    <ApplicationArea>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </ApplicationArea>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="DataArea">
    <DataArea>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Sync"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="SAP_JMS"/>
    </DataArea>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Sync">             <!-- source verb type -->
    <Sync>                              <!-- target verb type -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
    </Sync>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SAP_JMS">            <!-- source noun type -->
    <Reckitt>                           <!-- target nound type -->
        <!-- put your mappings here -->

        <xsl:copy-of select="//html"/>
    </Reckitt>
</xsl:template>
         <xsl:template match="OptivaSAPFormat" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is my xml

```
<OptivaSAPFormat>
  <IONUNIQUEID>FASTSKU_INB</IONUNIQUEID>
  <fsxml>
    <FSACTIONSETSTART KEYS="FASTSKU_INB">
      <KEYCODE>FASTSKU_INB</KEYCODE>
      <FSACTIONSETSTARTOBJECTLIST>
        <OBJ_LINE_ID>1</OBJ_LINE_ID>
        <TARGET_OBJECT_KEY>FASTSKU_FIELDS</TARGET_OBJECT_KEY>
        <TARGET_OBJECT_SYMBOL>PROJECT</TARGET_OBJECT_SYMBOL>
        <FSACTIONSETSTARTPARAM>
          <SRVROW_ID>1</SRVROW_ID>
          <PARAM_CODE>C_GLOBAL_ITEM_NUMBER</PARAM_CODE>
          <PVALUE>test - Global Item Number</PVALUE>
        </FSACTIONSETSTARTPARAM>
      </FSACTIONSETSTARTOBJECTLIST>
    </FSACTIONSETSTART>
  </fsxml>
<html xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:ns0="urn:ReckittBenckiser.com:GBL:TRACKWISE:Material">
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<STYLE type="text/css">
        .datagrid table { border-collapse: collapse; text-align: left; width: 100%; } .datagrid {font: normal 12px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: #fff; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #006699; -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; }.datagrid table td, .datagrid table th { padding: 3px 10px; }.datagrid table thead th {background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #006699), color-stop(1, #00557F) );background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #006699 5%, #00557F 100% );filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#006699', endColorstr='#00557F');background-color:#006699; color:#FFFFFF; font-size: 15px; font-weight: bold; border-left: 1px solid #0070A8; } .datagrid table thead th:first-child { border: none; }.datagrid table tbody td { color: #00496B; border-left: 1px solid  ;font-size: 12px;font-weight: normal; }.datagrid table tbody .alt td { background: #E1EEF4; color: #00496B; }.datagrid table tbody td:first-child { border-left: none; }.datagrid table tbody tr:last-child td { border-bottom: none; }.datagrid table tfoot td div { border-top: 1px solid #006699;background: #E1EEF4;} .datagrid table tfoot td { padding: 0; font-size: 12px } .datagrid table tfoot td div{ padding: 2px; }.datagrid table tfoot td ul { margin: 0; padding:0; list-style: none; text-align: right; }.datagrid table tfoot  li { display: inline; }.datagrid table tfoot li a { text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;  padding: 2px 8px; margin: 1px;color: #FFFFFF;border: 1px solid #006699;-webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px; background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #006699), color-stop(1, #00557F) );background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #006699 5%, #00557F 100% );filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#006699', endColorstr='#00557F');background-color:#006699; }.datagrid table tfoot ul.active, .datagrid table tfoot ul a:hover { text-decoration: none;border-color: #006699; color: #FFFFFF; background: none; background-color:#00557F;}div.dhtmlx_window_active, div.dhx_modal_cover_dv { position: fixed !important; }
    </STYLE>
<style>
        .toprow table {
border-collapse:collapse;
text-align:left;
width:100%;
}

.matnr {
font:normal 16px/150% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background:#fff;
overflow:hidden;
border:0px solid #006699;
-webkit-border-radius:3px;
-moz-border-radius:3px;
border-radius:3px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="0" style="display:inline-block; *display: inline;zoom: 1;">
        <tbody class="datagrid2">
        <tr>
        <td class="matnr">Product Code:    </td><td class="matnr">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3061862</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table border="0" style="display:inline-block; *display: inline;zoom: 1;margin-left: 1cm">
        <tbody class="datagrid2">
        <tr>
        <td class="matnr"> Description: </td><td class="matnr">GAVIS,NL,DUO TABS X48 NL</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table border="0">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="toprow">
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                <th colspan="6">Header Data:</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="12%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Category:</td><td>GI Upper</td><td width="12%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Segment:</td><td>Double Action Tablets</td><td width="12%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Product Form:</td><td>Tablet Regular</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="12%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Cons. Prod. Size:</td><td>    48.000</td><td width="12%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Cons.Prod.Size UOM:</td><td>each [EA]</td><td width="12%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Brand:</td><td>Gaviscon</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="12%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Old Material No:</td><td>3011627</td><td width="12%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Global Initiative Number:</td><td>EXGI56</td><td width="12%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Global Initiative Name:</td><td>GVS - Existing</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="12%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Product Name:</td><td>GVS DOUBLE ACTION  12x4x48</td><td width="12%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Material Type:</td><td>Finished Product</td><td width="12%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Primary Pack Type:</td><td>BLI - BLISTER PACK</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Formula:</td><td>0041116</td><td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Local Project Type:</td><td>NEW TO MARKET</td><td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Local Project Name:</td><td>DUO TABS</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Promo SKU?:</td><td></td><td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Promo Type:</td><td></td><td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Launch Comment:</td><td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Co-packer Flag:</td><td></td><td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Co-packer Name:</td><td></td><td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Reason for sku setup:</td><td>NEW TO MARKET</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">SKU initiator:</td><td>Anton Vandermaesen</td><td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Change control number:</td><td>000000172735</td><td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Outer Case Facings:</td><td>  1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Prime Coding- Expiry:</td><td></td><td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Prime Coding- Format:</td><td></td><td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Secon. Coding- Expiry:</td><td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Project Number:</td><td></td><td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">New Barcode Req?:</td><td></td><td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Factory Catalogue No:</td><td>433</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid #0070A8" bgcolor="E1EEF4">EAN Category Desc:</td><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #0070A8">ITF code - 14 digits</td><td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid #0070A8" bgcolor="E1EEF4"></td><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #0070A8"></td><td width="15%" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold; border-bottom: 1px solid #0070A8" bgcolor="E1EEF4"></td><td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #0070A8"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="1" class="datagrid4" style="font-weight: bold" bgcolor="E1EEF4">Product Comment:</td><td colspan="7"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
</OptivaSAPFormat>
```

Answer (score 2):

XSLT expects well-formed XML; yours is not.

Fix the problem by replacing,

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

with

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

or

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></META>
```

See also **[How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)**

Comment: There is no closing tag for `<meta>` in HTML so that should not be different with XML or XHTML? Only `<meta/> should be used?

Comment: XML (and XHTML) require that all elements be self-closing or have closing tags.

Comment: No. XHTML does not require a closing tag. I'm not talking about the slash.

Comment: @Rob: That's a bold statement. Are you sure?

Comment: @zx485 I am positive.

Comment: @Rob: You're thinking of HTML, not XHTML.  XHTML must be well-formed XML.

Comment: Yes it does but it does not have a `</meta>` closing tag.

Comment: In XHTML, it must be `<meta/>` or `<meta></meta>`, not `<meta>`.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying there is no such thing as `</meta>` to close the tag.

Comment: @Rob: Use authoritative references to back your assertions, not random web sites:  [**XHTML™ 1.0 The Extensible HyperText Markup Language (Second Edition)**](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xhtml1-20020801/#h-4.6)

Comment: Yes. Now you answered my question in my first comment. I could not get that link quick enough as I thought  I had to leave.

Comment: thank you guys for your answers, it seems that there is no solution

Comment: you could use html tidy first and use `-asxhtml` option before running that against the XSLT.