# How to find the number of duplicate attributes within a single node in xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath

```
<Restaurant>
   <firstFloor type="chinese" price="High" type="Indian">
   <firstFloor type="chinese" price="High">
</Restaurant>
```

I am trying to find the number of duplicate attributes inside a single node using xpath 1.0.

Can anyone tell a method to find that `type` has been assigned two times in the first `firstFloor` node? Existing solutions does not provide solution to find the duplicate attributes within the same node (Compares sibling nodes)?

I am expecting for a xpath 1.0 answer however xpath 2.0 answer is also acceptable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you did so far?

Comment: This XML is not even valid... How is it generated? Is this under your control?

Comment: As per XML specification we cant make duplicate attribute in same element. check well formation of the XML.

Comment: Actually i am implementing a tool to find such violations in a xml file. More clearly i can say i am trying to implement following rule using xpath.                                   https://github.com/yaniswang/HTMLHint/wiki/attr-no-duplication

Comment: @NilucshanSiva In order to *use `XPath`*, you need a well-formed XML. No tool, capable of `XPath`, will accept your input. This is a string, which *looks like XML* - but it is not... There are tolerant parsers out there... In most cases such issues should not occur, so the producer of this XML has to fix this problem.

Comment: I suspect the ill-formedness is simply a typo and the firstFloor tags should have been self-closing. But the fact that the question has been closed as a duplicate on those grounds hopefully means the OP will take more care in future.

Answer (score 1):

**No XML tool, including XPath, can help you with your data, because your data is not XML.**

- XML does not allow two attributes with the same name on a single
  element.
- XML requires all elements to be self-closing or have end tags.

**See also:**

1. [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)
2. [Explanation of Well-formed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085)

Comment: Thank you. I am actually trying to implement one of the rule in https://github.com/yaniswang/HTMLHint/wiki/attr-no-duplication using xpath 1.0. Can you suggest any way to implement this feature only using xpath?

Comment: You've completely missed, or chosen to ignore, the entire point of this answer.  Re-read it more carefully.  Thanks.

Comment: @NilucshanSiva As pointed out above, **you cannot *use XPath* if the input is not *well-formed***.