# XML parsing: semicolon expected - bypass bad record in SQL

Tags: sql, xml, xml-parsing

I know the "XML parsing: semicolon expected" error is a data error, and not a SQL error. The first error I am trying to get rid of is the one about DTD subsets, so I am using CONVERT(xml, xml_data, 2), but then I get this:
Msg 9411, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
XML parsing: line 1, character 94, semicolon expected

I don't have access to modify the actual xml. I am querying. It is data in a table (with >1 million records, so I don't even know which record is throwing the error), received from a vendor as responses to API calls. I am trying to shred the xml in a stored procedure, in order to extract bits of data.
Is it possible to somehow bypass the records with the bad data? I am NOT processing row by row at the moment, nor do I want to.

Thanks!

I tried this, but it didn't work, either:

```
SELECT s.id as SessionID  
, st.iD as TransmissionID  
, st.TransmissionTypeID  
, st.xml_data  
, CONVERT(xml, replace(cast(st.xml_data as varchar(max)),'&','&amp;'), 2) as converted_xml  
, s.insertdt  
, st.responsecode
```

INTO #Session_transmissions
FROM XML_Sessions s with (nolock)
    join XML_Session_Transmissions st with (nolock) on s.id = st.tbl_Subscription_XML_SessionID
WHERE s.insertdt >= '3/1/2018`

This is what finally worked:

```
SELECT PrimaryKeyColumn, TRY_CONVERT(xml, VarcharColumn) AS XMLValue, VarcharColumn
```

FROM YourTable
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(xml, VarcharColumn) IS NULL
AND VarcharColumn IS NOT NULL;

Comment: Your problem is, that any xml based approach to get *into* the XML will need a well-formed xml in order to work. There are some tools. [This related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49008497/5089204) provides some links to tools / approaches how to deal with malformed xml. It might help to show an example of such a bad xml. Maybe a simple string-replace of `&` could help...

Comment: But if I string replace &. won't that impact my ability to parse the xml later?  Is there a way to identify the bad records, and only replace on the bad documents?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that the *missing semicolon* is triggered by an `&` character. This character is the signal to start an entity code, the semicolon ends this: `&lt;` encodes the `<`. If there is an `&` in the content intentionally, `&amp;` must be used. Replacing all `&` with `&amp;` can help, but can make things worse too. The problem is, that you have to deal with strings, which look like XML but they are not...

Comment: Which database are you using?
Is there any code you can show us?

Comment: If you do the string replace inside of a sub-query, you won't have to modify your existing data.

Comment: Tried this   `, CONVERT(xml, replace
     (replace
     (replace
     (replace
     (replace(Transmission_Data,
      '&','&amp;'),
      '<','&lt;'),
      '>','&gt;'),
      '"','&quot;'),
      '''','&apos;')
    , 2) as converted_xml`   in my SELECT, but am still getting the same error

Comment: @MarianneCollins this is SQLServer? which Version? Can you use Try_convert?

Comment: @MarianneCollins btw, replacing the `<>` must destroy the XML...

Comment: I ended up using this:  SELECT PrimaryKeyColumn,  
 TRY_CONVERT(xml, VarcharColumn) AS XMLValue,  
 VarcharColumn  
FROM YourTable  
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(xml, VarcharColumn) IS NULL  
AND VarcharColumn IS NOT NULL;