# Is there any way to process my rest of xml file despite of any fatal error like SAXParserException encountered

Tags: java, xml, parsing, saxparseexception

Is there any way to process my rest of xml file despite of any fatal error like SAXParserException encountered.

I tried with DOM, SAX and Stax parser. 
my XML is:

```
<employees>
 <employee>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>abc</name>
 </employee>
 <employee>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>abc</name123>
 </employee>
 <employee>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>abc</name>
 </employee>
</employees>
```

---

I am getting XML from a external source which I need to validate
As I process above xml with SAX, i will get fatal error - SAXParserException on first name of 2nd employee entity.
As per my scenario, I have to read and process all employees node who are not error prone. like 1 and 3 id's employee.

Comment: `<name>abc</name123>` is wrong. You probably see why.

Comment: If you can't control the XML content to make it valid, you need to use a fault-tolerant parser, or write one yourself. This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765194/how-to-parse-invalid-bad-not-well-formed-xml/44765546#44765546