# What is the best way of removing rogue ampersands in XML?

Tags: c#, regex, xml, linq-to-xml

(TLDR at the bottom)

We have a legacy system that has implemented its own XML reader/writer. The problem is that it allows a literal "&" inside a property value.

```
<SB nae="Name" net="HV & DD"/>
```

When I am reading the data using XDocument.Parse() method, this fails of course. I am looking at ways of sanitizing the data.

I am attempting to use regex to identify cases where this is happening.
To illustrate, consider this:

```
&(?!amp\;)
```

This will identify ampersand with a negative lookahead to ensure it isn't actually a correctly escaped ampersand. When I have identified these cases, I can substitute with a proper &

Of course, there is a problem that this will match other escaped character such &gt &lt &quot etc, so I need to unmatch those as well. Maybe using a more general form, like a regex unmatching ampersand followed by 2-4 characters and then semicolon.

But my worry is that there are other cases for ampersands that I am not thinking of and that are not represented in the few samples I have got. I am looking for a safe way that will not mess up proper xml.

**TLDR: How do I identify ampersands that are not part of proper xml, but are cases of unescaped ampersands in property values?**

Comment: Could you please provide some more examples of actual xml and the expected/desired matches for each?

Comment: How much legacy is "legacy"? If ever possible I'd repair the source rather than fix the product.

Comment: See also [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can substitute the following regex pattern with `&amp;`:

```
&(?!(?:#\d+|#x[0-9a-f]+|\w+);)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/3MTLY9/2

Comment: Very nice.  Added, with credit, to my [canonical dealing with bad XML QA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085).  Thank you.