# Dealing with XML malformed in some of his element attributes

Tags: html, xml

Having the next simplification of a problematic XML code:

```
<A>
    <B someAttr="http://someURL?par1=AAA&par2=BBB">
    </B>
</A>
```

...when I try to load it in the browser it provides the following error message:

```
Error de lectura XML: mal formado
Ubicación: file:///C:/GESMED/ws-eclipse-GESMED-ZCAS/Z-AUX/xml/3.xml
Número de línea 3, columna 43:  <B someAttr="http://someURL?par1=AAA&par2=BBB">
-------------------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Does somebody know how to fix it?

(Note: it complains about the the second '=')

Comment: You are right! changing '&' with '&amp;' solve the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&` must be escaped in XML as `&amp;` when not being used as an entity reference.

Update the originating program or edit the XML manually.  If you cannot control this input XML, then see [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765194/how-to-parse-invalid-bad-not-well-formed-xml)

> (Note it complains of the second '=')

`=` is fine.  The error arrow, `^`, is only pointing to `=` because it's the first character after `&par2` for which the lexer can know that it's not working on an entity name that will be ending with a `;`.