# XML closing tag messes up the file

Tags: python, xml

Basicly I download a few XML files and then append them with Element Tree. The problem is that the final file has these things:

```
<<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> - at the start of each new xml fil
...
</product_info> /><product_info> ...
```

where product info is the actual cosing tag and the /> is what is messing everything up.

I fixed the first part by removing the XML declaration in the original xml file with:

```
replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><','')
#I remove a closing bracet at the end because I cannot remove the opening bracet as it is not in the original file
```

I suspect the problem is that for some reason before each XML files is apeneded it is enclosed in some tag?

When I check the 'ET.SubElement(root,response_xml)' this is what prints:

```
<Element 'product_info article_id="0006303562403"...'
```

Could the  tag be the problem?

Comment: If your original files had that content, they weren't really XML in the first place. If the input files are real XML but the output files aren't, we'd need to see a [mre] with the shortest possible code (and sample input document) that makes that happen to speak to how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Your file won't qualify as XML if it's not [***well-formed***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085), and you generally cannot use libraries designed to parse XML on data that fails to meet the definition of XML.

Examples of failures to be *well-formed* include:

- Having any content before the XML declaration.
- Having multiple root elements.
- Not properly closing an element.
- Using characters not allowed in component names.  (XML attribute names may not start with a `'`, for example.)

You must fix the code that violates the rules of well-formedness, or edit the data manually to repair, or see this Q/A for other options:

- [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)