# How to split XML tags into key and value pairs in Java

Tags: java

I have a text file which contains different XML tags. I need to split these tags into key and value pairs. For example the following tag should be changed to Version:1.5

```
<manifest:Version>1.5</manifest:Version>
```

Expected output: Version:1.5

Is there any way to do this without using XML Parser?

Comment: Why don't you want to use an XML parser?

Comment: You can write the same logic how the `XML parser` libraries do XML tree traversal and identify `key/value` from XML tag. Do you want to do it for your learning purpose? Is there any other reason why you don't want to use `XML parser`?

Comment: Another option is to convert XML to JSON using online tool or Java org.json dependency (if you are using Java) and then print out JSON. If it is simple XML (non-nested), JSON printed would be simple, almost your required format.

Comment: @PrathapReddy: The document which I'm working on does not have a proper xml format. (it has Opening and ending tag mismatch). So, I need to do it manually.

Comment: There are libraries which helps you to parse malformed XML (eg: [JSoup](https://jsoup.org)). Hope this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44765194/how-to-parse-invalid-bad-not-well-formed-xml) provide more insights to you. I would recommend doing of our own implementation as a last option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already mentioned you don't want to use any `xml-parser` here is a sample code which will work in you case-

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class BadXmlParser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> tags = Arrays.asList("<manifest:Name>java</manifest:Name>", "<manifest:Version>1.8</manifest:Version>");
        tags.forEach(tag -> {
            String key = tag.substring(tag.indexOf(":") + 1, tag.indexOf(">"));
            String value = tag.substring(tag.indexOf(">") + 1, tag.indexOf("</"));
            System.out.println(key + ":" + value);
        });
    }
}
```

Never recommended approach to use in prod.

**Note:** You should put validation logic by you own this is just parsing logic provided