# How to read a xml file which is not well_formed?

Tags: xml-parsing

I am trying to read an XML file with xml.etree.ElementTree
it gives me an error when it reaches a specific line of the file. I was assuming that this is a regular XML file. please help me how can I resolve it?

```
xml_file =ET.parse("/Users/arash/project/my_project/extracting_features/TraceData.log").getroot()
```

[image: It is part of my file which at the line of 56526 it returns me an error said invalid token, not well-formed. Don't know why it is like that the only difference in that line is that it is a new tag with some new attributes added to the file. any help would appreciate]

Comment: Please edit your question and add the actual xml, not an image.

Comment: @JackFleeting thanks, the actual file is very big to trace it is about 12MB. that is why I just sent part of the file as a picture.

Comment: XML files which are not _well-formed_ are invalid. Sanitize the XML file with another tool before loading it. XML is strict (and not HTML, whose parsers are optimized to make sense of partially invalid files).

Comment: @zx485 thanks for your response. Is there any way to make cElementTree understand that ignores that part of the file? because I don't need that part of the XML file at all. the file contains 173370 lines so it is hard to change some parts inside of it.

Comment: @zx485 <Throttle Pcts/> this is the tag that makes the cElementTree raise not well-formed error.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/407651