# What is the mimetype / format of this XML like format?

Tags: xml, parsing, mime-types

I'm attempting to parse a markup file of unknown source and I can't find out how. It looks a lot like an XML type, but not exactly which makes parsing quite difficult.

```xml
<equipment type="2" id="35" level="1" quantity="1" lvlPoints="0" >
    <_float durability="-1" maxDurability="0" />
    <_intarrays>
        <statusValue 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 />
        <abilityLearnPoints />
    </_intarrays>
    <_string>
        <_type><![CDATA[EquipShortcut]]></_type>
    </_string>
</equipment>
```

In this example my parsing fails at the `statusValue` tag, which is not normal XML. Can anyone tell me how to read this?

Comment: if you don't need the line with `statusValue` just remove that line...

Comment: It appears that it might have something to do with http://api.orkframework.com/ but it's definitely not XML. Maybe it's supposed to be `<statusValue>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</statusValue>`??

Comment: @RuiCaramalho That does not work, there are lots of objects in this file that i need to parse with similar format

Comment: I don't know whether this helps, but this seems to be the class you're looking at: http://api.orkframework.com/class_o_r_k_framework_1_1_equip_shortcut.html

Comment: Oh wow, thanks, I didn't know that existed. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The only part of that file that prevents it from being [well-formed XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085) is this:

```
    <statusValue 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 />
```

Until you remove or repair that part, you cannot process the file with XML-based tools.

Remove it manually, convert it to something well-formed such as,

```
    <statusValue>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</statusValue>
```

or see the following for possible automated remedies:

- [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)

Comment: I know how to convert it to that format, but that is not my problem. I have to interface with another program that only accepts the format as describe in the question

Comment: Then your actual problem is that you have to infer a syntax from instances of limited sample size rather than from a standard specification such as XML or JSON.  We can't help with do that, and you will never be able to know that you've covered all cases.  Such are the problems intrinsic to dealing with data of undefined form.