# fix missing root node with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have a very big xml with no root node (oversimplified example):

```
<address>1</address>
<address>2</address>
<address>3</address>
<address>4</address>
```

I have tried to add the root node inside xmlstarlet to select and compute some data this way:

```
 xmlstarlet -q fo -R file.xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "count(//address)"
```

seems to work but removing all but first node, so calculation is not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<address>1</address>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML option, `-H`,

```
xmlstarlet fo -o -R -H -D file.xml
```

does better at recovery here as it wraps your rootless elements in `html` and `body` elements:

```
<html>
  <body><address>1</address>
<address>2</address>
<address>3</address>
<address>4</address>
</body>
</html>
```

Then your `count()` call,

```
xmlstarlet fo -o -R -H -D file.xml | xmlstarlet sel -t -v "count(//address)"
```

will return `4` as expected.

### References

- [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)

Comment: sadly, this is not working with my real xml as some errors arised using HTML ( Tag address-request invalid

Comment: See the extensive recommendations for dealing with malformed XML in the reference I provided in the answer.  If you're still stuck after that, post a new question with a representative [mcve] reflecting the new problem.