# How to parse a structured (XML Like) texts in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xml, parsing

I have a text data with nested format, like an XML format but is using brackets {} instead of <>. What would be the best way to parse this, maybe convert it to XML format? I will then manipulate it like display it on a page or save the info on data base.

This is how it looks like:

```
{myItem num="345"}
{subItem num="1"}
My Sub item Texts
{/subItem}
{subItem num="2"}
My Sub item Texts
{/subItem}
{/myItem}
```

As you can see, it looks like an XML format but it uses brackets.

Comment: You could replace `{` with `<` and `}` with `>`. (If the text in between can have `}`, it should be escaped with a backslash)

Answer (score 0):

read all the data into a string and use the replace function to replace all the '{' with a '<' and the same for '}' with a '>'

```
var str = "{myItem num="345"}{subItem num="1"}My Sub item Texts {/subItem}{subItem 
           num="2"}My Sub item Texts{/subItem}{/myItem}";

var res = str.replace("{", "<");
var res2use = res.replace("}", ">");
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless this "structured" language has a specification, it is not a formal language, and the parsing of it may tend more toward [Natural Language Processing (NLP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) than markup or programming language parsing due to the lack of a fixed grammar to follow.

Lexically replacing `{` and `}` with `<` and `>` and calling it XML presumes much, including:

- Do `{` and `}` only appear as markup?
- Are all other XML well-formedness rules followed?

As a very rough first cut, you might apply the above replacements and then follow the guidance provided by [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)