# Pre-parse / prepare XML file to swap < and > out of attirbutes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, .net-core, replace

I have a really big XML files and somehow they fail validation as user's used `<` and `>` instead of `&lt;` and `&gt;` in attributes.

Is there a way in C# .Net Core to replace all the `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` quickly?

I have XML like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rootXML test="b < a">
<inside anotherTest="i could have < and > in here">Hello < all</inside>
</tootXML>
```

The hard part is I don't know where the < and > are and the XMLs can be quite different.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have a really big XML file, you have a heap of junk.

Comment: Assuming you're just worried about attributes, preprocess the string to replace each `>` or `<` that appears after an odd number of `"` characters.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: That won't work.  Quotes can appear elsewhere besides as attribute value delimiters.  The inescapable problem is that it's impossible to parse an undefined language.  For a collection of practical methods to (try to) ameliorate such markup messes, see [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085).

Comment: In general, yes.   IE fi there is XML or HTML pasted into attributes or text nodes nothing will work. But in specific cases you can preprocess the text to make it valid.  `>` and '<` appearing in text nodes is more complex, but not terribly much so.    Text nodes always appear after `>` and are always followed by `</`.  Of course if the text contains `</` you're screwed.  But if it's just `>` or `<` you can figure it out.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Assuming rule-breaking to be bound by rules is unwise.