# Expat, pure C. How to ignore mismatched tags?

Tags: expat-parser

I have a malformed XML (comes from a vendor, no realistic way to fix it).
Working with an expat 2.2.9 (gcc 9)

I was hoping to do my own stack of tags with a hierarchy and do a forceful closer of less important tags once the more important tag is closed.
For example, consider this html:

```
<p><b>text</p>
```

The `<p>` has a priority over `<b>`, and once I see `</p>` I want to also silently close `<b>`.

But working with the standard example outline.c ( https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/blob/master/expat/examples/outline.c )
I see that expat does tag matching by itself.

```
$ ./outline < malformed.html
p
  b
Parse error at line 1:
mismatched tag
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
$
```

So my question is: how to tell expat, that I myself would do tag matching and XML_Parse() should not stop on such errors?

Or is there another C library which can handle such malformed XMLs?

Answer (score -1):

The XML specification requires XML parsers to be strict and not tolerate well-formedness errors. As a result, Expat does not offer a switch to ignore errors.

Comment: That is a pointless answer. I have malformed XML and cannot avoid it - it clearly stated in the question. I still need to read this XML.

Comment: Your question is "How to ignore mismatched tags?". There is no way with Expat. You can fix the issue at generator or use another library to parse the XML or pre-process the input to Expat or patch Expat at C level. Unpatched Expat is non-forgiving.

Comment: PS: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765546/11626624 helps.