# Parse error near slash n while running xml file

Tags: json, xml, xml-parsing

I'd tried to run this xml file but unfortunately it couldn't be parsed and I always receive the error : config.xml:2: parse error near `\n'
.

To be honest, I have no idea how to fix it.

```
<config control-bind="127.0.0.1:8059" version="1.0">
    <web-server context="/fisheye">
        <http bind="<IP Address>:8060"/>
    </web-server>
    <security allow-anon="true" allow-cru-anon="true"/>
    <repository-defaults>
        <linker/>
        <allow/>
        <tarball enabled="false" maxFileCount="0"/>
        <security allow-anon="true"/>
    </repository-defaults>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot have a `<` character in an attribute value.

Change

```
    <http bind="<IP Address>:8060"/>
```

to

```
    <http bind="&lt;IP Address>:8060"/>
```

and then your XML will be [*well-formed*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

### See also

- [Simplified XML Escaping (prioritized, 100% complete)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46637835/290085)
- [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)

Comment: I had the same error  ,  I assume that some mistake in the first line but I don't see where it can be

Comment: The mistake I showed how to correct is the only mistake preventing your document from being well-formed.  Everything else in your XML is well-formed.

Comment: If you're still getting the same error, then you should suspect that either (a) you did not properly apply the fix I suggested or (b) a different document than what you've posted is actually being parsed or (c) [least likely] the program parsing your XML is broken.