# How To Fix XML: Mismatched Tag

Tags: xml, well-formed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="abc_action_bar_home_description">Go to Home</string>
  <string name="abc_action_bar_up_description">Go Up</string>
  <string name="abc_action_menu_overflow_description">More Options</string>
  <string name="abc_action_mode_done">Done</string>
  <string name="abc_activity_chooser_view_see_all">View All</string>
  <string name="abc_activitychooserview_choose_application">Choose Apply</string>
  <string name="abc_capital_off">Close</string>
  <string name="abc_capital_on">Open</string>
  <string name="abc_menu_alt_shortcut_label">Alt</string>
  <string name="abc_menu_ctrl_shortcut_label">Ctrl+</string>
  <string name="abc_menu_delete_shortcut_label">Delete</string>
  <string name="abc_menu_enter_shortcut_label">Enter</string>
  <string name="abc_menu_function_shortcut_label">Fn</string>
  <string name="abc_menu_meta_shortcut_label">Meta</string>
  <string name="abc_menu_shift_shortcut_label">Shift</string>
  <string name="abc_menu_space_shortcut_label">Space</string>
  <string name="abc_menu_sym_shortcut_label">Sym</string>
  <string name="abc_prepend_shortcut_label">Menu</string>
  <string name="abc_search_hint">Search...</string>
  <string name="abc_searchview_description_clear">Clear Query</string>
  <string name="abc_searchview_description_query">Search query</string>
  <string name="abc_searchview_description_search">Search</string>
  <string name="abc_searchview_description_submit">Submit Query</string>
  <string name="abc_searchview_description_voice">Voice Search</string>
  <string name="abc_shareactionprovider_share_with">Share Object</string>
  <string name="abc_shareactionprovider_share_with_application">Share with %s</string>
  <string name="abc_toolbar_collapse_description">Collapse</string>
  <string name="hms_abort">Terminate</string>
  <string name="hms_abort_message">Do you want to terminate the download?</string>
  <string name="hms_bindfaildlg_message">%1$s does not use HMS Core properly. Try turning on Phone Butler or Settings, turning on all %2$s permissions (Self-Start, Associated Startup, etc.), and try again.</string>
  <string name="hms_cancel">Cancel</string>
  <string name="hms_check_failure">Check for HMS Core updates failed.</string>
  <string name="hms_check_no_update">Is Current</string>
  <string name="hms_checking">Detecting new version...</string>
  <string name="hms_confirm">Got it</string>
  <string name="hms_download_failure">Download of HMS Core installation package failed.</string>
  <string name="hms_download_no_space">There is not enough space left to download.</string>
  <string name="hms_download_retry">Download of HMS Core failed. Retry?</string>
  <string name="hms_downloading">Downloading HMS Core | Completed:%d%%</string>
  <string name="hms_downloading_loading">Loading</string>
  <string name="hms_downloading_new">Loading HMS Core</string>
  <string name="hms_gamebox_name">Game Center</string>
  <string name="hms_install">Install</string>
  <string name="hms_install_message">You have not installed HMS Core before you can use this feature. Install?</string>
  <string name="hms_push_channel">Default</string>
  <string name="hms_retry">Retry</string>
  <string name="hms_update">Update</string>
  <string name="hms_update_continue">Resume Download</string>
  <string name="hms_update_message">The HMS Core version is too old for this feature to be available until the latest version. Update?</string>
  <string name="hms_update_message_new">" The service requires the latest version of the following app to be installed for use: ·%1$s"</string>
  <string name="hms_update_nettype"> is currently a non-Wi-Fi network. Continue downloading?</string>
  <string name="hms_update_title">HMS Core</string>
  <string name="nav_app_bar_navigate_up_description">Go Up</string>
  <string name="nav_app_bar_open_drawer_description">Open Drawer Navigator</string>
  <string name="search_menu_title">Search</string>
  <string name="status_bar_notification_info_overflow">999</string>
  <string name="upsdk_app_dl_installing">Downloading Huawei app marketplace</string>
  <string name="upsdk_app_download_info_new">Install</string>
  <string name="upsdk_app_size">Size</string>
  <string name="upsdk_app_version">Version</string>
  <string name="upsdk_cancel">Cancel</string>
  <string name="upsdk_checking_update_prompt">Checking for updates...</string>
  <string name="upsdk_choice_update">Updates are available. Go ahead and upgrade.</string>
  <string name="upsdk_connect_server_fail_prompt_toast">Unable to connect to the server, please try again later</string>
  <string name="upsdk_detail">Details</string>
  <string name="upsdk_getting_message_fail_prompt_toast">Unable to get information, please try again later</string>
  <string name="upsdk_install">Need to use Huawei's official app market to upgrade, do you want to install it now?</string>
  <string name="upsdk_no_available_network_prompt_toast">The network is not connected, check your network settings</string>
  <string name="upsdk_ota_app_name">Apply</string>
  <string name="upsdk_ota_cancel">Later</string>
  <string name="upsdk_ota_force_cancel_new">Quit the app</string>
  <string name="upsdk_ota_notify_updatebtn">Update Now</string>
  <string name="upsdk_ota_title">New version found</string>
  <string name="upsdk_storage_utils">%1$s MB<string>
  <string name="upsdk_third_app_dl_cancel_download_prompt_ex">Do you want to cancel the installation?</string>
  <string name="upsdk_third_app_dl_install_failed">Setup Failed</string>
  <string name="upsdk_third_app_dl_sure_cancel_download">Confirm</string>
  <string name="upsdk_update_check_no_new_version">Is Current</string>
  <string name="upsdk_updating">Updating</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2):

General tips for finding a mismatched XML tag:

1. Use an XML editor.
2. Search for mistakenly self-closed tag (e.g. `<string/>abc</string>`)
3. Search all open tags to see whether one should be a closing tag.  (e.g. `<string>abc<string>` – this happens to be the problem in your case.)

In your case, specifically, change

```
<string name="upsdk_storage_utils">%1$s MB<string>
```

to

```
<string name="upsdk_storage_utils">%1$s MB</string>
                                           ^
```

and then your XML will be well-formed.

### See also

- [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)