# What is invalid character entity &ccb

Tags: xml, go

I've this playground: https://go.dev/play/p/uEpYEWaQaV0
But did not get what is the issue and why it is not working! and I'm getting the error:

```sh
invalid character entity &ccb
```

My code is:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type catalog struct {
    Id string `xml:"id"`
}

type price struct {
    Subtotal    int    `xml:"subtotal"`
    Currency    string `xml:"currency"`
    Total       int    `xml:"total"`
    PriceStatus string `xml:"price_status"`
}

type image struct {
    Url string `xml:"url"`
    Id  int    `xml:"id"`
}

type product struct {
    Id         int    `xml:"id"`
    RetailerId int    `xml:"retailer_id"`
    Image      image  `xml:"image"`
    Price      int    `xml:"price"`
    Currency   string `xml:"currency"`
    Name       string `xml:"name"`
    Quantity   int    `xml:"quantity"`
}

type order struct {
    Product product `xml:"product"`
    Catalog catalog `xml:"catalog"`
    Price   price   `xml:"price"`
}

type Iq struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"iq"`
    Order   order    `xml:"order"`
}

func main() {
    contents := `<iq from="s.whatsapp.net" id="162.120-3" type="result">
  <order creation_ts="1651703902" id="1046755402590219">
    <product>
      <id>8312993582051445</id>
      <retailer_id>291</retailer_id>
      <image>
        <url>https://mmg.whatsapp.net/v/t45.5328-4/279646282_7510595942346471_4295336878174066544_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_p100x100&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=c48759&_nc_ohc=OMyHhkGxzRoAX8Dn93Q&_nc_ad=z-m&_nc_cid=0&_nc_ht=mmg.whatsapp.net&oh=01_AVw_0loIIuK1LP-n5OL1hdpRmNYhAiUjLGk20FCclgNXCA&oe=62774C93</url>
        <id>7510595939013138</id>
      </image>
      <price>5000</price>
      <currency>SAR</currency>
      <name>coffee</name>
      <quantity>1</quantity>
    </product>
    <catalog><id>326185462964376</id></catalog>
    <price>
      <subtotal>5000</subtotal>
      <currency>SAR</currency>
      <total>5000</total>
      <price_status>provided</price_status>
    </price>
  </order>
</iq>`

    iq := &Iq{}

    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(contents), &iq)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", iq.Order)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on the answer from [@collapsar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/588916/collapsar)...

Despite the XML being malformed, you can still process it by creating a `Decoder` instance and turning off `Strict` mode:

```
d := xml.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader([]byte(contents)))
d.Strict = false
err := d.Decode(&iq)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("%v\n", iq.Order)
```

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/xtnyRfknUW1)

For reference, see https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Decoder.

Comment: Very useful.  Added with credit to the [*How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?* canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765546/290085).

Answer (score 3):

The xml in your code is not well-formed.

The xml fragment contains an element `url`  which contains a url with multiple parameters in its query string portion, separated by ampersands `&`.

This symbol has special semantics in xml in initiating an entity reference (kind of a symbolic constant) - you cannot use it in isolation.

Either write the url as a CDATA section (the contents of which are considered a literal, Syntax: `<![CDATA[`...`]]>`) or replace all occurrences of `&` with `&amp;` (using the entity reference for the sports and symbol; effectively used here as an escaping mechanism).

Comment: Thanks, the first option did not work with me: https://go.dev/play/p/PUYabxnaUZX, but the second one worked perfectly: https://go.dev/play/p/sqQJQog98Ug