# How to find element inside element and an attribute with XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, selector, text-extraction, xpath-2.0

I want to extract the following value from the following element

```
<div style="width: 15%" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" role="button" data-original-title="" title="" data-content="<i>15%</i><b>Web Design</b>" class="grid custom_popover"></div>
```

How to extract the 15 from this line`data-content="<i>15%</i><b>Web Design</b>"`
The selector is xpath selector.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very specific in regard to your example, but you can filter out the "15" from your XML with the following XPath:

```
substring-before(substring-after(//div/@data-content,'&lt;i&gt;'),'%')
```

It extracts the string between `<i>` and `%`.

---

With XPath-3.0 you could parse the attribute value with [`fn:parse-xml-fragment`](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation11/functions/fn/parse-xml-fragment.html):

```
translate(parse-xml-fragment(//div/@data-content)/i,'%','')
```

I guess that this is what you wanted; but below XPath version 3.0, you can merely apply string operations and have no real XML parsing.

Comment: Please, can you tell me how to merge with this //*[contains(@id,'provider')]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[contains(@data-content,'Search Engine Optimization')]/@data-content

Comment: Maybe just replace `//div/@data-content` in the above expressions with `//*[contains(@id,'provider')]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[contains(@data-content,'Search Engine Optimization')]/@data-content`.

Comment: @ShahidulIslamPranto: No use spinning your wheels at the XPath level when your data is not well-formed XML in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not XML (`<` may not appear in an attribute value) and should not be expected to work with any XPath.

The solution is to fix your XML at the source if you want to use XML tools such as XPath with it.  Otherwise, see the link below, or write custom code to parse the (non-XML) data.

### See also

- [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)