# Replace special characters from xml string

Tags: c#, xml

Is that possible to replace special characters E.G "<" to "& lt;" etc... from string which i read from XML file by File.ReadAllText(path) method without replacing brackets from xml tags ? For example:

```
<fragment>
<set-header name="MyHeader">
    <value>Sample text < </value>
</set-header>
</fragment>
```

I need to replace "<" this symbol from  tag without touching  this "< value>" brackets.

Its important to do that without using E.G XmlDocument class becouse i can't read it becouse of this special character and it throws an exception.

Comment: This file is not XML because it is malformed. Fix whatever produces it so that it escapes the `<` correctly.

Comment: Also, the classes contained in the [System.Xml.Linq Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq) escape/unescape automatically for you.

Comment: But i need to remove it especially from this sample and i asked it is possible to do that ?

Comment: what about  `string s = File.ReadAllText("filePath");` `s= s.Replace(" < ", " & ");`

Comment: @HosseinSabziani but it replace also < and > symbols from  nodes E.G < values >

Comment: That (`< values >`) isn't in your sample though. All the tags have a character directly after the `<`. Fundamentally, patching up broken XML is going to be painful and unreliable. It would be much better to go to the source of this data and ask them to produce valid XML.

Comment: (What happens if the sample text is actually `"Here's an element <foo>"` for example? How would you expect to tell that apart from a "real" element called `foo`?

Answer (score -1):

The classes contained in the [System.Xml.Linq Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq) escape/unescape automatically for you.

```cs
string xml = """
    <fragment>
        <set-header name="MyHeader">
            <value>Sample text &lt; </value>
        </set-header>
    </fragment>
    <fragment>
        <set-header name="MyHeader">
            <value>Sample text &gt; </value>
        </set-header>
    </fragment>
    """;

var doc = XDocument.Parse($"<root>{xml}</root>");
foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("value")) {
    Console.WriteLine(element.Value);
}
```

Prints:

```
Sample text <
Sample text >
```

Note that you must embed these fragments into a single root element, otherwise you will get an exception telling you that you have more than one root element.

---

The other way round works as well:

```cs
var doc = new XDocument(new XElement("test", "value = <x> "));
string xml = doc.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(xml);
```

Prints:

```xml
<test>value = &lt;x&gt; </test>
```

---

**Attempt** to fix the bad xml:

```cs
// Escape the extra <
string xml = Regex.Replace(malformedXml, @"<([^\w/])", @"&lt;$1");

// Escape the extra >
xml = Regex.Replace(xml, @"(\W)>", @"$1&gt;");
```

This works only if the `<` can be identified as not being part of an open or closing tag. This regex searches for a `<` not followed by either a word character or a `/` and replaces it by `&lt;` and the following character (the group number 1 denoted as `$1`).

The second `Replace` replaces `>` not preceeded by a word character or a double quote.

Test:

```cs
string malformedXml = """
    <fragment>
        <set-header name="MyHeader">
            <value>Sample text < > </value>
        </set-header>
    </fragment>
            
    """;
string xml = Regex.Replace(malformedXml, @"<([^\w/])", @"&lt;$1");
xml = Regex.Replace(xml, @"([^\w""])>", @"$1&gt;");
Console.WriteLine(xml);
```

Prints:

```xml
<fragment>
    <set-header name="MyHeader">
        <value>Sample text &lt; &gt; </value>
    </set-header>
</fragment>
```

This works with this example of a malformed XML, but since we don't know all possible ways the XML could be malformed, we have no guarantee that this will always work.

The only good solution is to fix the problem at the source, i.e., by the provider of this XML.

Comment: Your first solution: Isn't the point of OP's question that the problematic "XML" has not `&lt;` but `<` as text?

Comment: Your second solution: Wouldn't this fail for preserve the `<` chars that begin tags?

Comment: His xml is malformed and cannot be parsed. Maybe the chances to parse it with the [Html Agility Pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/) are better. Otherwise create the xml as I have shown, by using the `XDocument` stuff. This will produce well-formed xml.

Comment: @kjhughes, What I have shown under "Prints:" is the actual output of a console application. So yes, it works.

Comment: But if i have in xml < that symbol instead of & lt; it thows an exception, what i can do with it ?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: But the code above **Prints:** doesn't show an example similar to OP's where the need is to repair the bad "XML".  Yes, had the provider of the bad "XML" followed your suggestion and used an API, OP wouldn't be in this predicament.

Comment: If `<` is followed by a space, then string replace will work. If it is followed by something else not being a letter, `Regex.Replace` might work. Otherwise try the Html Agility Pack or fix it manually. And if you are in control of the app creating this xml, fix that one.

Comment: That's right.  It's a tough problem where ideally the originator of the bad "XML" would correct the problem at the source.   Otherwise, see the detailed suggestions and references in the [canonical answer I wrote to addressing this class of problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765546/290085).  OP's case in particular would benefit from the **.NET** solutions listed under option **#2** and/or the regex's under option **#3** if the problem cannot be solved at the source (per option **#1**).

Comment: (For the record, although I pointed out issues with your answer, I did not downvote -- it's clear you're sincerely trying to help.)

Comment: Please se the last addition to my answer under "Attempt to fix the bad xml:". This actually works with your bad xml.