# Extracting info between two tags with re

Tags: python, xml, python-re

I need to parse a text file containing xml. Usual xml parsers don't work with it, I tried, so I decided to do this using python's re. The problem is that I can't find the right pattern to get everything between  and  without including these.

The closest pattern I got is r"(().+(</w>))" but it has two problems:

1. It includes ending tags
2. It covers EVERYTHING from the first  to the last  which I don't need, I need to have every tagged word with all its features and tags as a separate element

Here's the text sample:

```
<p><se><w><ana lex="сообщить" sem="t:speech ca:noncaus d:pref" gr="V pf tran ger act praet"/>Сообщив</w> <w><ana lex="я" sem="r:pers" gr="S-PRO sg 1p dat"/>мне</w> <w><ana lex="об" gr="PR"/>об</w> <w><ana lex="это" sem="r:dem" gr="S-PRO n sg loc"/>этом</w>, <w><ana lex="Говоров" sem="t:hum r:propn t:famn" gr="S famn m anim sg nom"/>Говоров</w> <w><ana lex="приняться" sem="der:v ca:noncaus d:pref" gr="V pf intr med m sg praet indic"/>принялся</w> <w><ana lex="яростно" sem="ev dt:humq der:a" gr="ADV"/>яростно</w> <w><ana lex="колотить" sem="t:impact ca:noncaus t:sound" gr="V ipf tran inf act"/>колотить</w> <w><ana lex="на" gr="PR"/>на</w> <w><ana lex="компьютер" sem="t:tool:device r:concr" gr="S m inan sg loc"/>компьютере</w> <w><ana lex="гневный" sem="t:psych:emot r:rel der:s" gr="A n sg acc inan plen"/>гневное</w> <w><ana lex="письмо" sem="r:concr t:text" gr="S n inan sg acc"/>письмо</w> <w><ana lex="председатель" sem="t:hum r:concr d:nag" gr="S m anim sg dat"/>председателю</w> <w><ana lex="гильдия" sem="t:group pt:set r:concr sc:hum hi:class" gr="S f inan sg gen"/>Гильдии</w> <w><ana lex="российский" sem="dt:topon r:rel der:s" gr="A pl gen plen"/>российских</w> <w><ana lex="адвокат" sem="t:hum r:concr" gr="S m anim pl gen"/>адвокатов</w> <w><ana lex="Мирзоев" sem="t:hum r:propn t:famn" gr="S famn m anim sg dat"/>Мирзоеву</w> <w><ana lex="Г" gr="INIT abbr"/>Г</w>. <w><ana lex="Б" gr="INIT abbr"/>Б</w>. <w><ana lex="Гасан" sem="t:hum r:propn t:famn t:persn" gr="S persn m anim sg nom"/>Гасан</w> <w><ana lex="Борисович" sem="t:hum t:patrn r:propn der:s" gr="S patrn m anim sg nom"/>Борисович</w> <w><ana lex="правовед" sem="der:comp t:hum r:concr t:prof" gr="S m anim sg nom"/>правовед</w> <w><ana lex="известнейший" sem="der:a d:super r:qual" gr="A m sg nom plen"/>известнейший</w>, <w><ana lex="депутат" sem="t:hum r:concr" gr="S m anim sg nom"/>депутат</w> <w><ana lex="государственный" sem="dt:space r:rel der:s" gr="A f sg gen plen"/>Государственной</w> <w><ana lex="дума" sem="t:ment r:abstr" gr="S f inan sg gen"/>думы</w>, <w><ana lex="а" gr="CONJ"/>а</w> <w><ana lex="потому" sem="der:apro r:dem" gr="ADV-PRO"/>потому</w>, <w><ana lex="как" gr="CONJ"/>как</w> <w><ana lex="уверенный" sem="t:ment der:v dt:ment r:qual" gr="A m sg brev"/><ana lex="уверить" sem="t:speech ca:caus d:pref" gr="V pf tran partcp m sg brev pass praet"/>уверен</w> <w><ana lex="судья" sem="der:v t:hum r:concr d:nag" gr="S m anim sg nom"/>судья</w>, <w><ana lex="понять" sem="t:ment ca:noncaus der:v d:pref" gr="V pf tran sg act fut 3p indic"/>поймёт</w> <w><ana lex="и" gr="CONJ"/>и</w> <w><ana lex="его" sem="r:poss" gr="A-PRO"/>его</w>   <w><ana lex="гнев" sem="r:abstr" gr="S m inan sg acc"/>гнев</w> , <w><ana lex="и" gr="CONJ"/>и</w> <w><ana lex="его" sem="r:poss" gr="A-PRO"/>его</w> <w><ana lex="беспомощность" sem="t:humq r:abstr der:a" gr="S f inan sg acc"/>беспомощность</w> <w><ana lex="перед" gr="PR"/>перед</w> <w><ana lex="адвокатский" sem="r:rel der:s dt:hum" gr="A pl ins plen"/>адвокатскими</w> <w><ana lex="сюрприз" sem="r:abstr" gr="S m inan pl ins"/>сюрпризами</w> <w><ana lex="и" gr="CONJ"/>и</w>
```

Comment: Don't  post images of text.  Format it as code instead (which I was about to do before you converted it to an image).  If XML parsers don't work with it, it could be HTML which doesn't strictly follow XML rules.  `re` doesn't deal will with nested tags.

Comment: You can find many examples using ill-advised technique of trying to parse XML with regex, but you really should use an XML parser instead for reasons that have been rehashed so many times on this site already.  You say "usual XML parsers don't work with it"?   See the second duplicate link for how to deal with not-well-formed "XML".

Comment: Parser which I tried can't build a proper tree for this file, since somewhere in the 10000th line there is on tag missing and the whole thing crashes down. I tried to use TheElementTree XML

Comment: Fix the problem at the source or see [How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44765194/290085)

Comment: You “p” and “se” tags are never closed.