How to ignore text content `]]>` when parsing XML in Python?
When producing XML documents with user-supplied text content and saving them into a data store, I made the (admittedly wrong) decision to not escape > inside text data. Because of this decision, I now somehow have an XML document that looks like this:
<foo>this is some text ]]></foo>

It has what appears to be the end of a CDATA element, but there is no trace of the beginning. It has proven tricky to parse the way I want.

The standard library xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring function raises a ParseError:
ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 25


Using lxml.etree.fromstring raises an XMLSyntaxError:
XMLSyntaxError: Sequence ']]>' not allowed in content, line 1, column 24


I found the recover keyword argument that can be supplied to an lxml.etree.XMLParser, which does allow parsing but discards the text content.
Input
parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(recover=True)
element = lxml.etree.fromstring("<foo>this is some text ]]></foo>", parser=parser)
lxml.etree.tostring(element)

Output
b'<foo>]&gt;</foo>'



What I am trying to find is an XML parser that is able to ignore ]]> inside the XML content.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44765546/407651

In XML ]]> must be escaped as ]]&gt; unless the ]]> is ending a CDATA section.  See duplicate link for advice to fix the errant "XML" at its source if at all possible and further recommendations if you're stuck with the bad "XML".
